# How to query multiple columns in Dynamodb with node js

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a project with Dynamodb and Nodejs. I need a solution for query on multiple fields like `select * from table where name=this and age=22 and active=this and area=this`. I need a solution with query only scan is not allowed to me. If it is possible then please let me know with a sample nodejs script.

Comment: Please provide the key attributes for this table to provide the solution.

Comment: @notionquest you can use personId as key attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code.

1) Change the table name

2) Change login credentials if you are using the AWS DynamoDB service. The below code uses local DynamoDB service

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var creds = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', 'session');

AWS.config.update({
    region : "us-west-2",
    endpoint : "http://localhost:8000",
    credentials : creds
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var table = "tablename";

var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'personId = :personIdval', 
    FilterExpression : '#name= :nameVal and age= :ageVal and active=:activeVal and area=:areaVal',
     ExpressionAttributeNames : {
        '#name' : 'name'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':personIdval' : '7',
        ':nameVal' : 'this',
        ':ageVal' : 22,
        ':activeVal' : 'this',
        ':areaVal' : 'this'
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```